# Does illustrator cs support wacom tablets?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I can use it fine with photoshop, and found out how to activate the wacom pressure sensitivity/angle feature. But with illustrator, it doesn't seem to register my strokes using the brush tool.

Does anyone know how to make illustrator cs5+ responsive to a wacom tablet?

Answer (score 1):

The brush tool isn't pressure sensitive by default - but there are ways to do pressure sensitive tablet drawing in Illustrator:

- The **Blob Brush tool** - but first you need to double click on the icon and set width to pen pressure. This creates paths where the  fill area is linked to pressure. When shapes of the same colour overlap, they join into one shape.
- **Art brushes** can be set to be pressure sensitive in their settings.  This creates paths where the stroke width profile is linked to pressure. I'd recommend this approach  personally - it's much more flexible and adjustable.

For example, for a simple, bog-standard brush where the width of the stroke is linked to pen pressure and remains adjustable, make a circle, select it, and create a new art brush from it from the Brushes window, using with settings at the top something like these (note '**Width:**' at the top and '**Overlap**' at the bottom), then, use that with the brush tool:

[image]

Also note how you can tick 'Preview' at the bottom and adjust how sensitive to pressure this line should be using the sliders at the top, any time after you've drawn using the brush, and you can completely replace the brush with a new one any time. Go vectors!

---

For *serious* freehand-drawn vector artwork in Illustrator, I'd suggest looking at this question on the graphic design SE site and trying out the (non-free) suggested add-on (Dynamic Sketch in DrawScribe from astutegraphics.com) - [Pressure-sensitive freehand drawing of vector paths that are editable with the Illustrator Width tool?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/16269/pressure-sensitive-freehand-drawing-of-vector-paths-that-are-editable-with-the-i)